# Create bootable file for imac

Tags: boot, mac, usb-flash-drive

I am an intern at a company and I have been provided an Intel atom system which certainly is not gonna be able to run smoothly at this age of online everything, so I requested a change and they invited me to fix a imac that does not have a operating system as I had never used a mac but I still thought installing a mac from a bootable pendrive is easy but well apparently its not. I don't know where I can get an ISO file and how do I make a pendrive bootable.

Comment: What model/year? You might not even need to create a iso - many macs will let you install the OS off the internet

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it's a mid 2007 imac

Comment: Spiff's answer covers why I was asking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Macs introduced since about 2012 can do "Internet Recovery" if you boot while holding down Command-Option-R. So that's the first thing to try.

If Internet Recovery is not an option in your situation, you sorta need a working Mac to revive a Mac with no bootable OS partition. From the working Mac you can go to the Mac App Store to download the latest OS (which comes as an installer app). Inside the OS installer app is a command-line tool called "createinstallmedia" that you invoke to create a bootable OS-installer partition on your USB flash drive. The full procedure is documented here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

By the way, Mac disk images are Apple-proprietary `.dmg` files, not the simpler `.iso` format that was popularized by Linux. There *might* be ways to use non-Apple OSes to mess with `.dmg` files, but it's probably a lot of hassle, and you'd have to figure out how to do the work of the "createinstallmedia" tool by hand, which involves, among other things, copying certain files (which are required for booting) into certain special locations on the target volume.